# NodeJS @azure/service-bus: How to renewLock for a message

Tags: node.js, locking, azureservicebus, servicebus

As I may handle message for long time which exceeded maximum locking time. I would like to know the syntax in NodeJS to renew message lock.

```
let { ServiceBusClient, ReceiveMode } = require('@azure/service-bus'),
serviceBusClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(SERVICE_BUS_SECRET),
queueClient = serviceBusClient.createQueueClient(XXX_QUEUE),
receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.peekLock),
errorHandler = function() {
    ...
},
messageHandler = function(message) {
    // want to renew message lock here
}

receiver.registerMessageHandler(messageHandler, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Do you have any other concerns, if you have no other concern, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @JimXu. 1 more question, how to call `deadletter()` as it mentioned function is not defined when I call `brokeredMessage.deadletter()`.

Comment: When we call the method `deadletter`, we need to provide `DeadLetterOptions ` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/service-bus/servicebusmessage?view=azure-node-latest#deadLetter_DeadLetterOptions____key__string___any_

Comment: Hi @JimXu, I still have no idea on how to call it. I created another question, please advise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457989/nodejs-azure-service-bus-any-example-to-send-message-to-deadletter-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use the method `registerMessageHandler`, we can provide the option `maxMessageAutoRenewLockDurationInSeconds`. It means that the maximum duration in seconds until which the lock on the message will be renewed by the SDK automatically. But please note that this auto-renewal stops once the message is settled or once the user-provided onMessage handler completes its execution. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/413077fd3664ac95dd2e45197b25a32ea79bebb7/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/test/stress/stress_messageManualLockRenewal.ts#L57) and [here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-service-bus/7.0.0-preview.5/interfaces/messagehandleroptions.html)

Besides, if you want to manually renew the lock, please set `maxMessageAutoRenewLockDurationInSeconds` as zero.

For example

```
import {
  SendableMessageInfo,
  ServiceBusClient,
  OnMessage,
  OnError,
  delay,
  ReceiveMode,
  ServiceBusMessage,
  MessagingError,
} from "@azure/service-bus";
const connectionString =
  "";
const queueName = "myqueue";
let receivedMessage: ServiceBusMessage;
let elapsedTime = 0;
const interval = 1000 * 10;
const testDurationInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60;
async function sendMessage(): Promise<void> {
  const ns = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const client = ns.createQueueClient(queueName);
  try {
    const sender = client.createSender();

    const message: SendableMessageInfo = {
      messageId: "test",
      body: "test",
      label: `test`,
    };
    console.log("send");
    await sender.send(message);
    await sender.close();
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    await ns.close();
  }
}
async function receiveMessage(): Promise<void> {
  const ns = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);

  const client = ns.createQueueClient(queueName);

  try {
    const receiver = client.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.peekLock);
    const receiverPromise = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
      const onMessageHandler: OnMessage = async (brokeredMessage) => {
        receivedMessage = brokeredMessage;
        console.log("Received message: ", receivedMessage.messageId);
        const startTime = Date.now();
        while (elapsedTime < testDurationInMilliseconds) {
          // simulate the user making an async call that takes time.
          await delay(interval);
          const data = await receiver.renewMessageLock(receivedMessage);
          elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;

          // log how long we've executed.
          console.log(`still executing after ${elapsedTime}`);
          console.log(data.toJSON());
          console.log("\n");
        }

        await brokeredMessage.complete();
        console.log("Completed message: ", receivedMessage.messageId);
      };

      const onErrorHandler: OnError = (err) => {
        if ((err as MessagingError).retryable === true) {
          console.log(
            "Receiver will be recreated. A recoverable error occurred:",
            err
          );
          resolve();
        } else {
          console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
        }
      };

      receiver.registerMessageHandler(onMessageHandler, onErrorHandler, {
        autoComplete: false,
        maxMessageAutoRenewLockDurationInSeconds: 0,
      });
    });
    await receiverPromise;
    await receiver.close();
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    await ns.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the current way of doing auto renew of message locks? This isn't in 7.0.2?